# Getting accurate IP through proxy

Tags: php, ip

Currently our domain will point to certain proxy IP (due to protection service) and all the traffics will go through the proxy IP and only route back the valid traffic to our server.

Here is my problem, I have an application to capture visitor's IP and save to database once they had login to our member site, I have below function to get IP and its was saved as a test.php for testing purpose:

```
function get_client_ip() {
$ipaddress = '';
if(getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
   $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
   $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
   $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
   $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
  $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
   $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
else
   $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';

return $ipaddress; 
}

echo get_client_ip();
```

However if I access directly `https://domain.com/test.php`, the IP is not what is expected (it's totally different from what I checked in whatismyip.com). I've been contact to our service provider, they told we must access URL like `https://x.x.x.x/~sitename/test.php` (where x.x.x.x is our VPS server IP) to capture accurate visitor IP, YES! it's works when I tried the URL, but back to the technical issue in coding, how can I **integrate** `https://x.x.x.x/~sitename/test.php`in this function to tell the code get IP from the provided URL??

Please help!!

Comment: A more complete description of the networking setup would be helpful here. How is the server configured so the difference in paths makes a difference in remote IPs...?

Comment: I have no idea on how is the server is setup, but we has SSL and the http will auto redirect to https through .htaccess, I tried using http and it is works also to capture expected IP.

Comment: Traffic to `https://domain.com/test.php` goes through a reverse proxy, whereas traffic to `https://x.x.x.x/~sitename/test.php` does not? Is the reverse proxy server sending the correct header with the visitors IP? What reverse proxy are you using on your domain?